# Why does a try-catch around an Assert make the test pass?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm just starting out with WebDriver/C#/NUnit and wondered why the following code results in a pass and not a fail:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

try
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Goooooogle", driver.Title);
    Console.Write("Passed");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);    
}
```

Also what is the difference between AssertionException and Exception?

Comment: `Exception` is the base class for all exceptions in C#, whereas I imagine that `AssertionException` is an exception thrown for if the assertion fails for whatever reason.

Comment: ...why wouldn't it? If you catch the error, as far as the test is concerned, *nothing went wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

The test simply passes because you catch the AssertException that the incorrect Assert throws.

Remove the try-catch altogether, so the exception it throws tells the test runner that the test failed.

You generally don't want to be using try-catch in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Most (.net) unit test frameworks assume that the test was successful if:

- none of the assertions fails
- If no exception was thrown.

Comment: So if exceptions are thrown, most unit test frameworks will say all is well? This is not true at all. Unless the test is expecting an exception, the exception will bubble up and fail the test.

Comment: @CodeYoshi I'm fairly certain that is what Dave Mertens meant, and the point was merely unclear due to poor grammar.

Comment: Well my comment will help his answer if that is what he meant. If not, it will still help the OP.